# Things that defined by WebIDL

Tags: firefox, firefox-os, b2g

After reading this post,
http://mcc.id.au/2013/lca-webidl/

I have some questions in the page 20,

1. What happens when you pass too many/few arguments.
2. What happens when you grab a Function corresponding to an IDL operation and apply it to some other type of object.
3. How interface inheritance corresponds to a prototype chain.
4. How DOM objects are stringified.

Can anyone give a specific explanation or example to these points.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If you pass too many arguments the extra ones are ignored.  Try `document.getElementsByTagName("a", "b")`.  If you pass too few, you get an exception: `document.getElementsByTagName()`.
2. If you apply a WebIDL operation to the wrong type of object, you get an exception.  See http://heycam.github.io/webidl/#es-operations step 4 under "Try running the following steps".  `document.getElementsByTagName.call(document.body, "div")` for example.
3. Interface inheritance corresponds to a prototype chain as described at http://heycam.github.io/webidl/#interface-prototype-object but in brief if you have `interface Foo : Bar { };` then `Object.getPrototypeOf(Foo.prototype) === Bar.prototype`.  So for example, the prototype of `HTMLElement.prototype` is `Element.prototype`.
4. DOM objects with a stringifier defined (e.g. `HTMLAnchorElement`) are stringified however the relevant specification defines them to be.  All other objects become "[object MostDerivedInterfaceName]".